# How to update the month automatically for a directory within a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ftp, winscp

I need to be able to update the month via windows in my batch script so that the target directory is always the current month (In numerical format, e.g 01). This saves me having to manually update it every month.
This is the solution I have come up with:

```
option confirm off
set month=%date:~3,2%
open ftp://ftp@IP/2022/%month%
synchronize local -preservetime \\localserver\battest\2022\%month%
close
exit
```

I am new to batch scripts so I am not sure if the month variable will work for directories or if there are any other issues with this script that I am not noticing.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: it will work like you wrote

Comment: This is not a batch file! You seem to mix up a batch file with an FTP script. What FTP client are you using? the Windows built-in `ftp.exe`?

Comment: @aschipfl we are using winSCP I believe. I can confirm that we have been doing this in a batch script in the past and it was very similar to the above. However I am not sure if there is FTP scripts are housed in Batch files or something else.

Comment: @Squalo I have tried testing this script, however CMD returned the following error:
`batch           abort
confirm         off
Unknown command 'set'.
Error!
Blat v3.2.16 (build : Aug  7 2016 22:51:22)
32-bit Windows, Full, Unicode`

Comment: No, this is not a Windows batch file but a script for the FTP client (perhaps they also call it batch script confusingly), which is something completely different. That is why `set` is reported to be an invalid command since this is a true batch file command. Hence either your FTP client supports commands for date/time extraction, or you could write a Windows batch file that first determines the date portion as needed, dynamically creates a (temporary) FTP client script and controls the FTP client using that script. Anyway, I added the [tag:winscp] tag, so experts in that topic might attend…

Comment: As @aschipfl suggests, the statements in the question are a mix of `cmd` .bat script and `ftp` script commands. `ftp` says `bye` at the end.

Comment: @Msj321, your problem is not with the "set" command, you can mix batch with ftp script in a different ways (for example you can launch ftp script from batch script). So create script with your ftp commands (which can be started standalone) and start it with batch script!